# Is it a bug or some other reason?

Tags: discussion

In following image (screenshot of Active section), it is showing modified by Amit.

[image]

I noticed this in active questions, but when I browsed question and answers, I didn't notice any edit in question or answers or new answer.

So what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug.

Not all activity on a question is visible to everyone. The question was bumped because there was new activity on the question. However, the activity was flagged and deleted by a moderator which is why you're not seeing anything new.

Comment: Not a bug then definitely experience could be improved ;) It wasted my 1 or 2 minutes.

Comment: It's network-wide behavior, feel free to ask on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Nothing we can do about it here.